# How to connect to SQL Server installed on another PC?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have to deploy an application on multiple computers and i want that the SQL server should be installed on one PC how can i connect all PCs to the SQL server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your application uses app.config for storing connectionString then you may edit appname.exe.config. If not then you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the connection string in your application that uses DB to point to your SQL server, like this:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

For example, if the name of your SQL server host computer is `nysqlsrvr1`, and your database is called `appdb` connection string would look like this:

```
Data Source=nysqlsrvr1;Initial Catalog=appdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Make sure the user running your DB application has permissions to access the database, or replace `Integrated Security=SSPI;` with appropriate user name and password. You can find more information about DB connection strings here [http://www.connectionstrings.com/](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005).

Answer (score 1):

Look in your `web.config` or `app.config` file and adjust the server address. Possibly the current value is `localhost`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you find more explanations.